# Smoothability of compact Alexandrov surfaces with curvature bounded from below

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

Let $(X,d)$ be compact metric space of curvature greater than $-1$ (in the sense of comparison triangles), assume that its Hausdorff dimension is $2$. Then a result of Perelman says that $X$ is a 2-dimensional manifold.

### Claim

$(X,d)$ can be Gromov-Hausdorff approximated by a sequence of Riemannian surfaces $(M_i,g_i)$ such that $\int_{M_i}|K_{g_i}|dv_{g_i}$ is bounded.

To see this :

1. A version of the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem holds ([Machigashira, The Gaussian curvature of Alexandrov surfaces](https://doi.org/10.2969/jmsj/05040859)), which implies that $(X,d)$ is an Alexandrov surface with bounded *integral* curvature.
2. Any such surface can be approximated by smooth Riemannian surfaces with bounded integral curvature. See Reshetnyak, Geometry IV, Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences.

### Question

Is any compact Alexandrov surface of curvature greater than $-1$ approximated by a sequence of smooth compact Riemannian surfaces with curvature bounded from below (by -1, or something else if this helps) ?

Maybe this is classic but I didn't find explicit results of this kind.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Edit: Addressing Igor's comment I'd like to correct the references I gave. The correct reference for the exact argument I sketch should be the original book by Alexandrov ["Intrinsic Geometry of Convex Surfaces"](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?r=1&pg1=CNO&s1=29518)(Chapter 7, section 6, Lemmas 1-3). In the later book by Alexandrov and Zalgaller a similar (but necessarily more complicated) argument is given for the case of surfaces with bounded integral curvature (Theorem 10, page 84). One can reconstruct the original proof in the easier case of curvature bounded below from that one but it requires some work.*

This is indeed classical and is due to Alexandrov ( see the book by Alexandrov and Zalgaller ["Intrinsic geometry of surfaces"](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?r=1&pg1=CNO&s1=216434)).

The general structure the proof is as follows. You take a very fine triangulation of $X$ and substitute the curved triangles by triangles with the same sides in the space form of constant curvature  $-1$. This will give you a polyhedral surface of curvature $\ge -1$ (you only need to check that the cone angles at vertices are $\le 2\pi$ which is immediate from the definition of an Alexandrov space).  Away from the cone points the metric will be smooth of constant curvature $-1$. The cone points can then be easily smoothed to get a smooth metric of $\sec\ge -1$. The hard part  is to show that the resulting polyhedral surface is close to the original space $X$.

A more interesting result is another theorem of Alexandrov ( ["Intrinsic Geometry of Convex Surfaces"](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?r=1&pg1=CNO&s1=29518)) that locally any 2-dimensional Alexandrov space of $curv\ge -1$ is isometric to a level set of a convex function in $\mathbb H^3$. When the lower bound is 0 he proved an even  sharper result that any 2-sphere of curvature $\ge 0$ is isometric to the boundary of a convex body in $\mathbb R^3$.

BTW,  the result you attribute to Perelman that a 2-dimensional Alexandrov space is a topological manifold is actually due to Alexandrov too.

Comment: Where exactly is this argument in Alexandrov-Zalgaller's book? 

Comment: @Igor sorry, I don't have the book and I haven't looked at in in quite a while  but  my recollection is that I read it there.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realized that Alexandrov already proved the result about the topology of 2-dimensional Alexandrov surfaces. Maybe my mistake come from "Geometry IV" of Reshetnyak, which defines surfaces of bounded *integral* curvature assuming at the beginning that the underlying space is a topological surface.

By the way, Alexandrov-Zalgaller is on my desk these days, I'll have a look at it.

Thanks again.

Comment: After looking at Alexandrov-Zalgaller's argument, I must admit I would not be comfortable quoting it as an answer to the OP's question. Given that the question is of considerable interest it is unfortunate that there seem to be no proof in the literature.

Comment: @Vitali, on your edit: which chapter is this in? I have the new edition of Alexandrov's "Intrinsic Geometry of Convex Surfaces" published in his collected works and almost every chapter has section 6.

Comment: @Igor sorry,it's in Chapter 7. In case the chapter number differs in your edition the chapter is called "Existence of a closed convex surface with a given metric".

Comment: @Vitali, I see nothing about smoothing in Lemmas 1-3. Also he only considers the case of positive curvature, but this must be a minor point. Smoothing at vertices is not a minor point. It may be fixed by the realization theorem in Chapter XII, section 2 which says every point in a space of curvature $\ge k$ has a neigborhood isometric to a convex surface is the 3-dimensional model space of constant curvature $k$. Of course, any convex surfaces can be approximated by smooth ones, giving the smoothing, and hopefully these smoothings can be glued. 

Comment: @Igor: Alexandrov doesn't mention smoothing but that is a minor point. He proves that $X$ can be approximated by  polyhedral surfaces with the same lower curvature bound. By construction the approximating surfaces are smooth and  have constant curvature outside of the cone points. Cone points are  isolated and it's trivial to smooth  such metrics with the same lower curvature bounds the way you smooth a flat cone by a surface of revolution.
The fact that he considers lower curvature bound 0 is a minor point too as all arguments are local. He discusses the general case in chapter 12.

Comment: BTW, Once you are trying to make the "idea of the proof" work, you get  into tedious details.
$$ $$
That means: If you have a complete clean and short proof then I am very interested.

Comment: @Anton No I don't have a short proof.  I admit it was wrong to call what I describe an "idea of the proof" as the hard part of the proof is missing but I haven't looked at Alexandrov's book in a long time and I could only remember the general structure of the argument when I wrote my answer.

Comment: This paper of D. Ramos http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.5554 gives a way to smooth out the cone points without messing with gluing. It constructs a smooth solution to Ricci flow for surfaces with conical singularities.