# Approximation of 2-dimensional Alexandrov spaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

Consider a closed 2-dimensional surface (not necessarily orientable) with a metric with curvature at least -1 in the sense of Alexandrov. It it true that on this surface there is a sequence of infinitely smooth riemannian metrics of Gauss curvature say at least -100 which converges to the given metric in the Gromov-Hausdorff sense?

A reference would be helpful.

Comment: With $-110$ replaced by some negative constant this goes back to Alexandrov-Zalgaller and Reshetnyak. I would read [Yu. G. Reshetnyak, "Two-dimensional manifolds of bounded curvature”,  MR1263963 (94i:53038)].

Comment: @IgorBelegradek : Thanks. This certainly answers my question.  Would you like to write it as an answer?

Comment: It seems one can approximate by Riemannian metrics with the same lower curvature bound. This is what is claimed in Theorem A.1
of https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.5461 which also contains a nice summary of basic facts about Alexandrov surfaces. I don't have a firm grip on this material and hence would rather not post my comments as an answer. I encourage you to check everything and then post it as an answer.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek : My impression is that Reshetnyak’s paper you mentioned discusses spaces of bounded curvature in a different sense: not bounded below (as I asked) but bounded in some integral sense. Theory of such spaces is also developed in Alexandrov-Zalgaller book. Unfortunately I did not find the  statement relevant in my case. However it is stated explicitly in the paper by Richard you mentioned without any proof or reference.

Comment: Any (possibly non-smooth) surface of curvature bounded below has bounded integral curvature, and this is explaned in Reshetnyak's article (which is detailed but not written elegantly, in my opinion). The approximation by Riemannian metrics holds in this larger class. Let me give a few more references, section 3 in  https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01967250/document, and https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.3407 or http://www.crm.sns.it/media/course/2102/SlidesPisa.pdf where you can learn more about bounded integral curvature on non-smooth surfaces. Also see https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.07755.

Comment: Right, but do all these riemannian metrics have uniformly bounded below curvature? My impression that they have only uniformly bounded integral of absolute value of curvature.

Comment: My understanding is that they also have curvature bounded below.

Comment: Actually, this question was asked before at MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86807/smoothability-of-compact-alexandrov-surfaces-with-curvature-bounded-from-below.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek : 1) My impression is opposite: surfaces with curvature bounded below have a bounded integral curvature, but not vise versa.  2) You are right: this question was asked 7 years ago. The discussion at your link shows that some experts do believe that the answer is positive, but it is unpublished and it is unclear if anybody checked the details.

Comment: I agree that being skeptical is the right approach. In the comments to his answer Kapovitch sketches why the approximating sequence has curvature bounded below.  I encourage you to check the details and decide for yourself. You can also ask Thomas Richard for a proof of this claim in his paper (which I gather is now published).